# jquery ajax synchronous http request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

i am using ajax and jquery to send an **synchonou**s http request to a php script in a web aplication to log out the user if incase the user decides to leave the page rather than logout.

i am using hte following code:

```
function close()
{
  return "If you exit you will be logged out ...!";
}
window.onbeforeunload = close;

$(window).unload( function () { 

$.ajax({
        url: "logout.php",
        async:false,
        success: function(msg){
        alert( "You have been logged out ...!");}
});     
});
```

the ajax is working in ALL cases apart from when i press the back button. When i press the back button i even get the success function running but when i check the php script has not run as i have a fwrite function in it to tell me it worked.
it is working in other cases apart from the back button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i am using ajax and jquery to send an asynchonous http request

The request in the code you've quoted is synchronous, not asynchronous.

If you're seeing the `success` function get called when you're not seeing the PHP code running, that means your browser has cached the previous result and reused it. You *may* be able to bypass that by adding `cache: false` to your request options.

Comment: i just tried adding the cache: false, it did not work. can it have anythign to do with the fact that when i press back it heads back to another php script ?

Comment: @user: If you're really seeing the `success` function get called, but you're really *not* seeing the logged line from your PHP, I can't see any other option than that the browser used a cached response or (apologies) that you're mis-observing. Regardless, doing anything on page unload is *extremely* unreliable (that code won't do what you want on Safari, Opera, IE9, prob. others), so I assume you must have a fallback in place (time-out, etc.). I would recommend not having the `alert` and simply taking any proactive logout you get from the unload as a *bonus*, not anything you actually rely on.